# iOS Swift - Is there a way to add a subview into a table cell and position it correctly?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, uilabel

So, here`s my problem:

I want to create a table to display some flight data. The idea is that each cell represents a trip (i.e all flights necessary to go from city A to B). Each flight has 3 properties which I would divide in separate labels, composing the line. Because of that, the cell must adjust its height accordingly.

This is what I`ve done so far:

My view controller class:

```
@IBOutlet weak var dispTable: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    dispTable.dataSource = self
    dispTable.delegate = self
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("DispCell") as? DispTableViewCell {
        let flight1: Flight = Flight()
        let flight2: Flight = Flight()
        curFlightsIda = [Flight]()
        Flight1.Num = "1221"
        Flight2.Num = "1331"

        curFlightsIda.append(Flight1)
        curFlightsIda.append(Flight2)

        for voo in curFlightsIda {
            let lbl = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50))
            lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
            lbl.text = voo.Num
            cell.contentView.addSubview(lbl)
        }

        return cell
    } else {
        return DispTableViewCell()
    }
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

The flight.num there is just for tests. I was able to create the label programmatically, but I feel that the way I`m going, the layout won`t work properly.

So, how can I create the labels representing the lines and place them correctly? Am I on the right track? I searched around and found about XIBs, but I'm not sure if it's better..? Honestly I`m completely lost and any help would be deeply appreciated.

I`m not sure if this helps, but it would be something like this:

TRIP CELL:

Flight1Num       Flight1Departure      Flight1Duration

Flight2Num       Flight2Departure      Flight2Duration

Flight3Num       Flight3Departure      Flight3Duration

Comment: You should use Auto Layout.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't.**

***Why:***

*cellForRowAtIndexPath* gets called for every cell (also during scrolling). If you are trying to do too much, it won't scroll smooth. Furthermore cells are reused (as *dequeue* indicates it). iOS only creates the number of visible cells instances plus one or two extra cells. If a cell is reused, you would need to remove the already added labels before adding new ones which leads to the next problem: How can you identify them (either search for all subviews and check if it is an instance of UILabel or use a tag and find them by tag.... anyway: If you are trying to do too much, it won't scroll smooth.

***Instead:***

Define the labels in your template cell 'DispCell' or create different template cell in your storyboard (and dequeue the correct one by name). There you can use storyboard layout constraints in order to position your labels correctly.

If you have a flexible number of curFlightsIda, you can either think about a max number (and hide empty labels) or maybe it works out to use a textfield instead of a label.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I was suspecting that it wasn`t the best way... So you're saying that I should create a single custom cell with, say, six flight lines ready and make the necessary elements appear according to the number of flights in the current trip?

And what would be the difference in using textfield instead of label?

Comment: It depends on the design, but yes: Simply have a prepared cell template. You can also use textfields, but it is editable by default. a label is read-only (so choose what is necessary).